# force a docker build to 'rebuild' a single step

Tags: docker

I know docker has a `--no-cache=true` option to force a clean build of a docker image.  For me however, all I'd really like to do is force the last step to run in my dockerfile, which is a `CMD` command that runs a shell script.

For whatever reason, when I modify that script and save it, a typical docker build will reuse the cached version of that step.  Is there a way to force docker not to do so, just on that one portion?

Comment: This has bitten me as well a few times. I've ended up inserting "dummy RUN" entries just to force that final step without invalidating the entire RUN block cache. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that this would invalidate the cache for *all* Dockerfile directives after that line. This is requested in [Issue 1996](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996) (not yet implemented, and now (2021) closed), and [issue 42799](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42799) (mentioned by [ub-marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285820/ub-marco) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013947/force-a-docker-build-to-rebuild-a-single-step/37018862#comment122401447_37018862)).

The [current workaround is](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996#issuecomment-172606763):

```
FROM foo
ARG CACHE_DATE=2016-01-01
<your command without cache>

docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date) ....
```

That would invalidate cache after the `ARG CACHE_DATE` line  for every build.

[acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013947/force-a-docker-build-to-rebuild-a-single-step/37018862?noredirect=1#comment114435305_37018862) having to use:

```
docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
```

---

[Another workaround](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42799#issuecomment-1006325840) from [`azul`](https://github.com/azul):

> Here's what I am using to rebuild in CI if changes in git happened:
>
> ```sh
> export LAST_SERVER_COMMIT=`git ls-remote $REPO "refs/heads/$BRANCH" | grep -o "^\S\+"`
> docker build --build-arg LAST_SERVER_COMMIT="$LAST_SERVER_COMMIT"
> ```
>
> And then in the Dockerfile:
>
> ```
> ARG LAST_SERVER_COMMIT
> RUN git clone ...
> ```
>
> This will only rebuild the following layers if the git repo actually changed.

Comment: I got error with purely `$(date)` and had to format the it: `... --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S) ...`.

Comment: @acdcjunior Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: [Issue 1996](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996) is closed for unknown reasons, however [Issue 42799](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42799) is open now.

Comment: @ub_marco Thank you. I have amended the answer accordingly.